# how to use select2 bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

im new at select2 im using bootsrap v3.3.6

how to plugin the select2 bootstrap?
i already input

```
<link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<select id="position" style="width: 15%">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option>One</option>
                <option>Two</option>
<script src="js/select2.js"></script>
 $("#position").select2({
        allowClear:true,
        placeholder: 'Position'
      });
```

but the output still like the default select2. not like bootstrap, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$("#position").select2(..)` instance should be inside `script` tags. Make sure you close the `select` tag. Make sure you're properly referencing the select2.css and select2.js and that there are no errors in the browser console.

http://codeply.com/go/YNg1JSaysI

Comment: can u send me link for the js and css u use im scared im make a mistake with the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code as follows:-

```
 <link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <select id="position" style="width: 15%">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option>One</option>
 <option>Two</option>
 <script src="js/select2.js"></script>
 <script>
 $("#position").select2({
 allowClear:true,
 placeholder: 'Position'
 });
 </script>
```

**Links are as follows:**

```
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2-bootstrap-css
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2?ref=driverlayer.com/web
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: im using the script sir. can u send me the link for plugin select2 js and select2.css and select2-bootstrap.css?

Comment: check the cdn links updated in the answer. That's all you need to ref.