# how do i install JQuery select2?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

i have been trying to install and use select2 for my drop-down but i just cant get it to work, i tried following what is documented here: [how to use select2 bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132875/how-to-use-select2-bootstrap) 
but still got no luck 
here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<body>
<script>

$("#disease").select2({
  allowClear:true,
  placeholder: 'Search for a disease'
});
</script>
<select id="disease" style="width: 40%;  position: relative;top: 220px; left: 182px; " name="tdisease" >
                        <option value="">Select Disease</option>
                         <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
                  <?php } ?> 
                     </select>

</body>
```

Comment: Where is your select2.js?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Where do you load jQuery and select2?

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle and your code (with some fixes) works ok. Why did you add `select2.css` twice?

Comment: When posting saying something "doesn't work" it's kind of important to detail *how* it doesn't work. Otherwise how do you expect people to know what the problem is? (In general; here it seems obvious.)

Comment: Where's your jQuery? What's in your JS console?

Comment: @KiranReddy check updated question

Im not getting any errors and by not working i mean my drop-down does not change, it stays the same

Comment: Also, if you're not running your `select2` function inside a DOM-ready function, you'll likely be trying to select2ize a DOM element that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install jQuery - Make sure you place it before the Select2 files.

Your code should look something like this:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
      </head>
      <body>

        <select id="disease" style="width: 40%;  position: relative;top: 220px; left: 182px; " name="tdisease" >
            <option value="">Select Disease</option>
            <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
            <?php } ?> 
        </select>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
           $("#disease").select2({
             allowClear:true,
             placeholder: 'Search for a disease'
           });
        })
        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: here is an example tutorial  https://youtu.be/gTNQOxvuUv0

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery.js script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And place your select2 call in `document.ready` like below

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $("#disease").select2({ 
            allowClear:true,       
            placeholder: 'Search for a disease'
        });
});
```